# Touchpad right click not working - How to enable touchpad buttons and keep two finger click?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, 19.04, 19.10, fedora

The right button on my touchpad only does left clicks. When I press in the lower right corner of my touchpad, a left-click is done.

How can I configure the touchpad to behave like on Windows, where I can press the physical button on the left side for a left click and the right hardware button for a right click?

I would also like to right-click using a two finger tap and disable the middle button area on the touchpad for the button press, so there are only areas for left and right clicks.

Answer (score 2):

On my Jetson Nano with Ubuntu 18.04, I ran into a similar problem connecting my Logitech TouchPad - this is what I did to make it work for me...

In a terminal window use the xinput cli - first find the id of your touchpad:

```
xinput list
```

In my case, the touchpad shows with ID 10; now get the setting for the touchpad:

```
xinput list 10
```

In my case I see: *libinput tapping enabled (360): 0*, meaning that the command id is 360 and the tapping is not enabled - so let's enable it:

```
xinput set-prop 10 360 1
```

After this, I can tap slightly with one finger (not a deep press) to left-click, with two fingers to right-click and with three fingers to middle-click.

You can try other settings as well, for example I also set Natural scrolling (the content moves with the swipe, not the scoll-bar) which is what I am used to.

```
xinput set-prop 10 286 1
```

Worked for me - hope it works for you too!

Comment: `xinput list-props 10` to view these properties. I think that was meant with `xinput list 10`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was tested on Fedora 31 Workstation in X11 mode (not Wayland) and should be compatible with Ubuntu 18.04+ and other distros using the same software (X11, GNOME, libinput).

## 1. Enable click emulation

Go to `Settings -> Devices -> Mouse and Touchpad` and enable `Tap to click`

## 2. Enable right click emulation through SoftButton Areas and enable middle button emulation

> **Note:** Middle button emulation gets enabled to *disable the middle button area* for the SoftButtons. It maps left+right click to middle click.

Put the following code into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-clickpad.conf` (as root)

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "libinput touchpad catchall"
    Driver      "libinput"
    Option      "MiddleEmulation" "true"
    Option      "ClickMethod" "buttonareas"
EndSection
```

### 3. Set GNOME default behavior to SoftButton Areas

> **Note:** May be optional?

Execute this in a terminal (as normal user):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'areas'
```

### 4. Reboot

Reboot and test that everything works as expected:

- Tap anywhere: left click
- 2-Finger tap anywhere: right click
- Press bottom left: left click
- Press bottom right: right click
- Press bottom middle: no middle click
- Press bottom left+right: middle click

### Troubleshooting:

> The underlying issue here is that most touchpads only have 1 hardware button, so the software handling the input must map that button press to a left click or right click based on the location of your finger at the time of the button press.

#### Check button mapping

To see what the button press maps to:

- Get the name of your input device by running `xinput list`
- Test the device events by running `xinput test 'device_name_or_id'`

Be aware that spaces and other special characters in the device name must be escaped or put in single quotes. Cancel the command by pressing `CTRL+C`.

The output should read `button press 3` for a right click and `button press 1` for a left click.

#### Middle button click is still emulated by pressing in the middle

Verify that the middle button emulation is **enabled** so that the software button area gets disabled by running

```
xinput list-props '<device_name_or_id>' | grep 326
```

The output should read `libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (326):    1`, if not then your touchpad isn't compatible with libinput or it's using another driver by default.