# Physical Mouse Buttons do not work on Lenovo Yoga X1, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics, button

**Problem**
The buttons above the touchpad that are supposed to be left-, middle-, and right-click do not work at all currently.

It used to work at some point in the past.

Just a few minutes after asking this question, my left-click is working again. The right-click button still does nothing ... unless when I right-click on the "Show Applications" button in the GNOME dock, then it opened the applications, just now, once. But now it is not working anymore again for ten clicks, then it works again once... Probably it is a [hardware issue](https://superuser.com/a/932655/291007). I have just booted into windows and the right-click is also not working there.

**Target**
I would like to have them work, so I can left-click and right-click *both* with the physical buttons and with the touchpad taps (one finger for left-click, two finger for right-click). The middle button should paste.

**Workaround**
I recently learned that triple-finger-tap emulates the middle button, so I *can* work. What I can not do is hold the right-click pressed while moving the mouse though.

**Attempt: gnome-tweaks**
Several answers recommend running `gnome-tweaks` and changing the mode of the touchpad to `Area`. It can be found under `Keyboard & Mouse > Mouse Click Emulation`.
Supposedly, it would then work both with the finger-tap emulation *and* with the physical buttons.

To my understanding, a relog after this change should suffice. When I tried this, none of the following made it noticeably change anything:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, `r`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, login
- reboot

So for now, I changed it back to the `Fingers` mode that it originally was at.

**Workaround 2**
Using above paragraph to change the settings to `Area` allow me to right-click using the lower-right area of the touchpad by clicking hard (so an actual click can be felt). It is possible to move the mouse using the touchpad at the same time. That is uncomfortable in comparison, but it works.

**Attempt: synaptics**

Some answers recommend to purge and reinstall the synaptics driver, by doing

```bsh
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

In my case, this fails with the following warning.

```bsh
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`apt list | grep synaptics` reveals that I have the HWE package already installed. So I decided to avoid breaking things further.

```bsh
apt list | grep synaptics

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev/bionic,bionic 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 all
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-16.04/bionic 3:14.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 all
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04/bionic 3:14.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64
```

**Attempt: xinput**
I saw some [claims](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240072/606260) that even though synaptics was installed, it was not actually in use and this should be done using `xinput` instead.

I do not understand which property would correspond to enabling the physical buttons. Here are my outputs:

```bsh
generic@motorbrot:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8004:00 06CB:CD8B Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8004:00 06CB:CD8B Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ sof-hda-dsp Headset Jack                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]

generic@motorbrot:~$ xinput list 13
SYNA8004:00 06CB:CD8B Touchpad              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0

generic@motorbrot:~$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'SYNA8004:00 06CB:CD8B Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (168):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (170): 2.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (350): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (351): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (352):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (353):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (354):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (355):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (356):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (357):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (334):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (335):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (358):    0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (359):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (336):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (337):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (338):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (360): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (361):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (362):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (363):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (364):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (341): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (342): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (346): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (347): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (291): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (292):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (293):    0, 0
    Device Node (294):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (295):    1739, 52619
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (348):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (349):   1
```

Comment: This question is very likely a hardware issue and as such can not be answered. The question body is potentially useful to future visitors, but it should not look like it is waiting for an answer.

Comment: I am having the same issue, on same laptop, with brand new hardware...

Comment: @gatoWololo fyi I have not yet been able to fix this. I just got used to only use the touchpad's tap/two-finger-tap/three-finger-tap to replace the buttons